# exlude folder with specific extensions after recursively search

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hello scripting guys,

```
    get-childitem -recurse -path "C:\test\Media" -include *.mp3  , *m3u, *.jpg
```

shows me my two subfolders “AudioAndJPG” including  *.mp3, *m3u, *.jpg fles and “VideoJPG” including *.avi, *.mkv, *.jpg files. (Of course only *.mp3, *.m3u and *.jpg are shown).
How can i exclude the whole folder which contains video and jpg files but show all folders which contains mp3, m3u and jpg files?

```
    get-childitem -recurse -path "C:\test\Media" -include *.mp3  , *m3u, *.jpg| Where-Object { ($_.Directory -notcontains "*.avi")}
```

Dosent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns directories containing list of extensions that do not contain avi:

```
gci -Recurse -include *.mp3  , *m3u, *.jpg | ? { !(gci "$($_.Directory)\*.avi") }
```

This will be much faster if you cache internal loop gci results for a directory.